# Can a diamond with Soul Bind be detected inside a living body?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Strange question!

If a creature has had Soul Bind used on them (which means their soul is trapped inside a black diamond) and then that diamond was implanted inside someone's body (say in their chest)... could it be detected through Detect Magic by someone else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see auras through opaque objects, within certain limits. The SRD doesn't list flesh as being opaque to the spell, and if we took "wood/earth" as the closest material, you'd need a wall several feet thick. Most people aren't that big. So yes, a mage should be able to see an aura.

I'd imagine that it would look really strange, though. Most mages would probably assume the person was wearing an amulet under clothing, and then get confused when no amulet was found. Bonus points if the person actually *is* wearing an amulet, but then the amulet is removed and the aura is still (roughly) where the amulet was.